# Regex in Cypress with contains

Tags: javascript, regex, cypress

Can anybody give me and hint in regards to regex in Cypress?
I have a variable called filename('filename.txt') and after someone has clicked a button the filename gets a suffix(filename.txt_32423442.abc).
It gets an underscore, a random number[0-9]+ of numbers and '.abc' at the end. I want to check it with contains from Cypress.

That would be my regex solution, but it doesn't work: filename+"_([0-9]+).abc"

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand on why `filename+"_([0-9]+).abc"` doesn't work? It's a valid regex for the pattern you describe.

Answer (score 0):

What does random number of numbers mean? 1 - infinity or 0 - infinity? If min is 0, you should put a * instead of +. Then, the regex should look like

```
/filename.txt_[0-9]*.abc/
```

https://regex101.com/r/K0i7Kq/1

Edit: To test regex with Cypress I don't use contains. I just assert the following expression:

```
expect(myRegex.test(myTextToTest)).to.equal(true)
```

I'm sure there should be better or more elegant ways to do the same but I find this pretty simple and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to construct a new regex variable with your filename variable and the following.

Here is the [regex proof](https://regexr.com/6v11j)

```js
const filename = 'filename.txt'
// '\d' matches any digit
const matcher = new Regex(filename + '_\d+.abc')

cy.contains(matcher).should('be.visible')
```